# Setting Elasticsearch publish_host and bind_host correctly for cluster and sniffing

Tags: elasticsearch

I've looked at some of the other questions around here but somehow I wasn't able to solve my probleme with them. I have an Elasticsearch cluster in a private network (acutally it's a Docker network). In the same network there is an application which talks with ES, that works fine.

Now I'd like to access and use the ES cluster from the outside. All my machines have a pair of IP addresses - private and public, on the public side only port 9200 is open. In principle this works, I can query the nodes.

However, I'd like to use sniffing and that's where it gets complicated. The nodes are configured with

```
network.bind_host=0.0.0.0
publish_host=internal.name[1,2,...]
```

So when I enable sniffing (with elasticsearch-py), I get `Cannot connect to host internal_ip[1,2,...]:9200 ssl:None [No route to host])`. I understand that the client gets a list of `publish_host`s.

So I could change `publish_host` to point to the external hostname / IP, however then I'd have to open the "internal" ports 9300 on the external IP.

Is there a way to configure ES to publish internal names or IPs only to other nodes in the cluster, but external one to sniffing clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure you are able to configure the http and transport modules in a different manner. This is very common not only with containers but also when you want to use diffenent NICs because of security or performance considerations.

All configuration options starting with network.* will be applied to both network modules with the same values. Using http.* and/or transport.* options you'll be able to define different settings for each of the network module.

Please have a look on the transport module (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-transport.html) and http module (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html) configuration for more in detail information.